# Open any File in a Memo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

In Notepad you can Open any File and it will display the raw data inside.

I would like to do this in a TMemo but have struggled to find out how to do this.

I managed to find this [code here.](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=944)

I modified it to a function and changed it slightly for my purposes:

```
function OpenBinaryFile(var Data; Count: Cardinal): string;
var
  Line: string[80];
  i: Cardinal;
  P: PAnsiChar;
  nStr: string[4];
  SL: TStringList;
const
  posStart = 1;
  binStart = 7;
  ascStart = 57;
begin
  P := @Data;
  Line := '';

  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (i mod 16) = 0 then
      begin
        if Length(Line) > 0 then
          SL.Add(Trim(Line));

        FillChar(Line, SizeOf(Line), ' ');
        Line[0] := Chr(72);
      end;

    if P[i] >= ' ' then
      Line[i mod 16 + ascStart] := P[i]
    else
      Line[i mod 16 + ascStart] := '.';
    end;

    SL.Add(Trim(Line));

    Result := SL.Text;
 finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It works, but it only displays in a fixed amount of characters per line, like this:

[image]

What do I need to change so it fills all the memo in the same way Notepad would?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it's the `if (i mod 16) = 0` test that is truncating the lines at 16 characters.

I believe that Notepad does the same as this code:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  s: AnsiString;
  Stream: TFileStream;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    SetLength(s, Stream.Size);
    if Stream.Size>0 then
      Stream.ReadBuffer(s[1], Stream.Size);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do
    if s[i]=#0 then
      s[i] := ' ';
  Memo1.Text := s;
end;
```

If you want to replace non-printable characters with `'.'` then you can easily do so by modifying the code above like this:

```
if s[i]<#32 then
  s[i] := '.';
```

Comment: That's great thank you David. I was reading some comments whilst looking for various solutions and some mention the use of BlockRead. The Files I am opening are relatively small, but do I need to consider it anyway, or does your answer not require this because it seems it is read through the Stream?

Comment: I would always use a stream rather than old style pascal io

Comment: Well I have never used old style Pascal, still learning modern Delphi :) The articles/snippets I was reading were probably outdated that might explain that. Your solution is really tidy and efficient, you make it look easy. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

`TStrings` became `TEncoding`-aware in D2009.  By default, `TStrings.LoadFrom...()` will use `TEncoding.Default` unless you tell it otherwise.  I would suggest implementing a custom `TEncoding` derived class that reads/writes raw 8-bit data, eg:

```
type
  TRawEncoding = class(TEncoding)
  protected
    function GetByteCount(Chars: PChar; CharCount: Integer): Integer; override;
    function GetBytes(Chars: PChar; CharCount: Integer; Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): Integer; override;
    function GetCharCount(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): Integer; override;
    function GetChars(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer; Chars: PChar; CharCount: Integer): Integer; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function GetMaxByteCount(CharCount: Integer): Integer; override;
    function GetMaxCharCount(ByteCount: Integer): Integer; override;
    function GetPreamble: TBytes; override;
  end;
```

.

```
constructor TRawEncoding.Create;
begin
  FIsSingleByte := True;
  FMaxCharSize := 1;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetByteCount(Chars: PChar; CharCount: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := CharCount;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetBytes(Chars: PChar; CharCount: Integer; Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): Integer;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := Math.Min(CharCount, ByteCount);
  for i := 1 to Result do begin
    // replace illegal characters > $FF
    if Word(Chars^) > $00FF then begin
      Bytes^ := Byte(Ord('?'));
    end else begin
      Bytes^ := Byte(Chars^);
    end;
    //advance to next char
    Inc(Chars);
    Inc(Bytes);
  end;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetCharCount(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := ByteCount;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetChars(Bytes: PByte; ByteCount: Integer; Chars: PChar; CharCount: Integer): Integer;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := Math.Min(CharCount, ByteCount);
  for i := 1 to Result do begin
    Word(Chars^) := Bytes^;
    //advance to next char
    Inc(Chars);
    Inc(Bytes);
  end;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetMaxByteCount(CharCount: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := CharCount;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetMaxCharCount(ByteCount: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := ByteCount;
end;

function TRawEncoding.GetPreamble: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
end;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var
  Enc: TEncoding;
begin
  Enc := TRawEncoding.Create;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('filename', Enc);
  finally
    Enc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent information and code example thank you very much Remy. It amazes me that there are always more than one way to do something in programming and Delphi - yet more often that not I cannot figure out one single way! Your solution is completely different to David's, but both show different approaches which is really useful :)